# Анимация уменьшение картинки

Tags: swift, spritekit

Есть анимация на увеличение картинки, а как сделать наоборот уменьшение?

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
          snapshotView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
          }, completion: {
            finished -> Void in
                 snapshotView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        })
```

Comment: передать в makeScale значения меньше 1.0 (например 0.5)

Comment: Спасибо) А он у меня сейчас уменьшается только в одно направление (вправо) можно ли уменьшение сделать влево?

Comment: у view.layer есть свойство anchorPoint, оно задает точку привязки. поставьте ее на 0.5-0.5 (центр) и тогда уменьшение должно оставлять ваш объект на том же месте. измнение anchor point желательно делать до добавления вашего вью на экран (если это сделать позже, вью переместится по экрану)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы уменьшить, вам надо передать в makeScale значения меньше 1.0 (например 0.5).

при этом, уменьшение будет происходить относительно точки привязки (левый верхний угол по дефолту). Чтобы это изменить: у view.layer есть свойство anchorPoint, оно задает точку привязки. поставьте ее на 0.5-0.5 (центр) и тогда уменьшение должно оставлять ваш объект на том же месте. изменение anchor point желательно делать до добавления вашего вью на экран (если это сделать позже, вью переместится по экрану)